# Prestashop localhost giving Refused to Connect error

Tags: prestashop

So I went ahead and transferred my Prestashop (1.6) site from one server to another. I got the database set up and the files fully loaded. When trying to access the server itself, it pulls up no problem. I also see the directory where the Prestashop files are located when accessing the server through the public IP address.

Now, I want to get into the Prestashop store, but I'm getting an error. I have updated my `settings.inc.php` file in the `config` directory. It has the correct `DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS`. The problem seems to be with the `DB_SERVER`.

When I set the `DB_SERVER` to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` then I get a 'This site can't be reached' error. Then if I switch the `DB_SERVER` to the Public IP Address then I get `Link to database cannot be established: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Directory Not Found` error.

Is there something that I'm missing here? I've scoured the apache2 directory for correct settings and I can't seem to figure it out. Any ideas or suggestions to put me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You must change your store domain information within your database. Look into table `ps_configuration` and update fields `PS_SHOP_DOMAIN` and `PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL` also go to table `ps_shop_url` and update all necessary information there as well

Comment: This didn't work for me, also set the PS_SSL_ENABLED as explained in the @AJoe16 answer

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before (in a previous answer), you have to update both tables "ps_shop_url" and "ps_configuration"

```
UPDATE `ps_shop_url` set domain="localhost", domain_ssl="localhost" where main=1 and domain="website.com";
UPDATE `ps_shop_url` set physical_uri="/localhost-project-folder/" where main=1 and domain="localhost";
UPDATE `ps_configuration` set value="localhost" WHERE name IN ("PS_SHOP_DOMAIN", "PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL");
```

I would add the following step: update the "ps_configuration" by disabling SSL:

```
UPDATE `ps_configuration` set value="0" WHERE name like "PS_SSL_ENABLED";
```

And make sure to access you localhost project as follows: http://localhost/project/ and not https://localhost/project/ (please note the https).

Comment: THIS! PS_SSL_ENABLED worked, thanks